Accessing user phone numbers with Google login for test users
I’m trying to implement Google login in my application and want to access users’ phone numbers.
I’ve created an unverified app in the Google Console, enabled the Google People API, and added the phone number scope (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.phonenumbers.read). I’ve also added test users for testing purposes.
However, when I attempt to retrieve phone numbers, I receive a 403 error, indicating that my client does not have permission to access that information.
Is it possible to access user phone numbers in an unverified app, even for test users, or does the 403 error indicate that Google restricts this access for unverified applications?

Can you provide your code? I understand that you are dealing with phone numbers only but I am thinking that there are part of your code that's causing the issue.
